# Swift Error The data can not be Read because it is missing

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I am trying to display the data from API . Here is the API Link .https://coinmap.org/api/v1/venues/ . I want to display the properties of the Vanues Array fields into IOS app . I created model by using Quick type . I use the Map like **self.vanues = respone.results.map{$0} but still same result** Here is the model .

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Coin: Codable {
    let venues: [Venue]
}

// MARK: - Venue
struct Venue: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let lat, lon: Double
    let category, name: String
    let createdOn: Int
    let geolocationDegrees: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, lat, lon, category, name
        case createdOn = "created_on"
        case geolocationDegrees = "geolocation_degrees"
    }
}
```

I convert that to list by using another swift file . Here is the code .

```
import Foundation
struct VanueResponse: Decodable {
    let results: [Venue]
}
```

Here is my Network Manager .

```
import Foundation

class NetworkManager {
    
    func getCoins(from url: String, completion: @escaping (Result<VanueResponse, NetworkError>) -> Void ) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            completion(.failure(.badURL))
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(.other(error)))
                return
            }

            if let data = data {
                //decode
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(VanueResponse.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(response))
                } catch let error {
                    completion(.failure(.other(error)))
                }
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is the presenter class.

```
import Foundation

class VenuePresenter : VanueProtocol{

    // creating instance of the class
    private let view : VanueViewProtocol
    private let networkManager: NetworkManager
    private var vanues = [Venue]()
    var rows: Int{
        return vanues.count
    }
    // initilanize the class
    init(view:VanueViewProtocol , networkmanager:NetworkManager = NetworkManager()){
        self.view = view
        self.networkManager = networkmanager
    }
    
    
    func getVanue(){
        
        let url  = "https://coinmap.org/api/v1/venues/"
        
        networkManager.getCoins(from: url) { result in
            
            switch result {
            case.success(let respone):
                self.vanues = respone.results
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.view.resfreshTableView()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.view.displayError(error.localizedDescription)
                    print(Thread.callStackSymbols)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    
    

    func getId(by row: Int) -> Int {
        return vanues[row].id
    }
    
    func getLat(by row: Int) -> Double {
        return vanues[row].lat
    }
    
    func getCreated(by row: Int) -> Int {
        return vanues[row].createdOn
    }
    
    func getLon(by row: Int) -> Double? {
        return vanues[row].lon
    }
    
    
}
```

I put the break point and find this in console windows .

[image: console window]

Here is the screenshot when I run the Applications .

[image: error]

Comment: can you show entire error instead of just error.localizedDescription. I think the problem is you are not having the properties optional. So if there is some key missing in the api it will throw error because you have not made those optional in your model. And you will get what the actual error if you print whole error object.

Comment: when I started writing code it show me the property needs to make it optional and I made it but still not clear@ShreeshaKedlaya

Comment: I got what is the problem. In `VanueResponse` struct just replace results with `venues` it will work just fine. And also make all the properties optional.

Comment: You are decoding `VanueResponse`. So it has to have same signature as response. And also you could use `Coin` struct instead of `VanueResponse`.

Comment: Again, can you show the detailed error message by using `error` instead  of `error.localizedDescription`? `print(error)` and include the error message

Comment: ok. I changed to print error and added the screenshot of the console windows . But it returning nil or 0 ..@JoakimDanielson

Comment: Replace `self.view.displayError(error.localizedDescription)` with `self.view.displayError(error)`. To fix the issue you have to know the `DecodingError`

Comment: The displayError func is expecting a parameter I already mentioned error for both case . With first case it saying the data can not be read because it missing and second approach is using the print statement to find the error and it is returning nil or 0 . I do not know why ?@vadian

Comment: Again and already mentioned by others `error.localizedDescription` returns a pointless generic error message. You need the `DecodingError` which tells you exactly what's wrong. Alternatively just `print` the `error`.

Comment: I use the print statement like print(error) and put the break point with the break point I can see the values are nil or 0 . I already added the screenshot in the question . After that it not printing the error into console windows.@vadian

Comment: Your console is the Variables View. To activate the **Console** press ⇧⌘C or click on the symbol bottom right.

Comment: Here it is .. other(Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"results\", intValue: nil) (\"results\").", underlyingError: nil)))other(Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"results\", intValue: nil) (\"results\").", underlyingError: nil)))@vadian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Decoding Error is clear:

The key in the root dictionary is `venues` (not `results`) so the proper struct is `Coin`.

In `getCoins` replace both occurrences of `VanueResponse` with `Coin`